# How do I place data into TKinter?

Tags: tkinter

I'm very new to Python and TKinter so sorry if this is a basic question. I want to build a voltage data logging using TKinter to create a GUI. My question is how do I place a number into a TKinter widget? In the code below, how do I place `x` into the widget?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

root = Tk()
x=3+3

answer=Label(root, text= "x")
answer.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your first step should be to work through a tkinter tutorial. There are several. One is here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying `text="x"`, remove the quotes: `text=x` to pass in the value of `x`.